# How to set the background color of a span to a outer div?

Tags: html, css

I want the background color of the Reset password to max width of the outer div..The background color must be in full width of the header section.how to do it?

**html:**

```
<div class="forgot-inner">
            <!--Forgot-header-->
                    <div class="forgot-header">
                        <div class="header">
                        <span>Reset Password</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
</div>
```

**css:**

```
        .forgot-inner {
        max-width: 331px;
        margin: 39px auto;
        padding: 13px 24px;
        background: #fff;
        text-align: center;
        border: 1px solid #aaa;
        border-radius: 4px;
        box-shadow: 2px 11px 31px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    }

    .forgot-inner .forgot-header .header{
        border-bottom:1px solid #aaa;
        text-align:left;
        background-color:#edefed;
        width:100% !important;
        font-size: 14px;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
```

[This is how it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3H7nS.png)

Answer (score 0):

```css
 .forgot-inner {
        max-width: 331px;
        margin: 39px auto;
        padding: 13px 24px;
        background: #fff;
        text-align: center;
        border: 1px solid #aaa;
        border-radius: 4px;
        box-shadow: 2px 11px 31px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    }

    .forgot-inner .forgot-header .header{
        border-bottom:1px solid #aaa;
        text-align:left;
       
        width:100% !important;
        font-size: 14px;
        font-weight: bold;
    }  

 .forgot-inner .forgot-header .header span{background-color:#edefed;}
```

```html
<div class="forgot-inner">
            <!--Forgot-header-->
                    <div class="forgot-header">
                        <div class="header">
                        <span>Reset Password</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
margin: -13px -24px;
```